# Where can i find the original definition of the reserved identifier "__CLIBNS"?

Tags: c++

I see the following definition in the standard header file stdint.h of the ARM compiler:

```
             #undef __CLIBNS
             #ifdef __cplusplus
             namespace std {
             #define __CLIBNS ::std:: 
             extern "C" {
             #else /* ndef __cplusplus */
             #define __CLIBNS
             #endif /* ndef __cplusplus */
```

What is the significance of this? 
 Where can i find the original definition of the reserved identifier "__CLIBNS" ?

Comment: every IDE should have function to find definitions/declaration of variables, macroes and so on. For instance on Visual Studio, it is enough to move the cursor(the flickering |, not mouse) into the word `__CLIBNS` and press f12, and Visual Studio will do its best to find where it is defined

Comment: Who says that there *is* an "original" definition? Do you know what `#undef` does?

Comment: what i really want to ask is "where can i find the detailed information of the key word(__CLIBNS)"? In another words, i want to know what is the meaning of "__CLIBNS" by itself?

Answer (score 0):

> Where can i find the original definition of the reserved identifier "__CLIBNS" ?

In line 4 of the code you posted.

The code is written like this to ensure that the macro is only defined once, and it resolves to `::std::`.